# How to get a system environmental variable that is overridden by a user environmental variable in Java?

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, environment-variables

In a windows 7 environment, I have a variable VARA="x" defined under System's enironmental variables and the same variable VARA="y" defined under the user's environmental variables. how do i get the value of VARA as defined in the system's environmental variables section. I always get the user value not the system one. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to access the [registry](http://twall.github.com/jna/3.4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Advapi32Util.html#registryGetStringValue%28com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg.HKEY,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna).

```
Advapi32Util.registryGetStringValue(WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\Environment",
    name);
```

You can also access user variables:

```
Advapi32Util.registryGetStringValue(WinReg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
    "Environment",
    name);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

`System.getenv()` returns the value of the environment variables at the time your app launched. How those values were set is irrelevant and inaccessible to the JVM

Answer (score -1):

In Java you just type:

```
 String variable = System.getenv("WINDIR");  
System.out.println(variable);
```

and you get the system's environmental variable.

If you want to search for all system's environmental variables:

```
Map<String, String> variables = System.getenv();  

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : variables.entrySet())  
{  
   String name = entry.getKey();  
   String value = entry.getValue();  
   System.out.println(name + "=" + value);  
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.